# Can't include header files from other project

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a package with just one header file and use this header file from other packages.

The header file is in HeaderProjectName/include/HeaderProjectName/HeaderFile.h

In the CMakeLists.txt "catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include)" is defined and so is "install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/ ..." that was commented out in the default file.

I added the HeaderProjectName as both run and build dependency in the client's package.xml.

Still on compiling I get error that no such file as "HeaderProjectName/HeaderFile.h".

What could be wrong or what am I missing?

Using catkin on Groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54010/can%27t-include-header-files-from-other-project/) by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on 2013-02-01**:
what your'e describing sounds correct. try this: instead of running catkin_make, go into the build folder and run make VERBOSE=1. you'll be able to see the include paths that way and get us more info.

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-01**:
Try adding project dependency  in manifest.xml

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-02-01**:
When the cpp file (that needs the header from other project) is compiled, then my header's directory is not used.

**Comment by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on 2013-02-05**:
could you paste the output of the compile with verbose=1 out as well as your cmakelists.txt and package.xml for both projects? i don't have enough information right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the client package you need to find_package your 'HeaderProjectName', something like this will add the includes path from HeaderProjectName:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS HeaderProjectName <other packages here>)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

An alternative method is that you can find_package HeaderProjectName directly:

```
find_package(HeaderProjectName REQUIRED)
include_directories(${HeaderProjectName_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3